# Interesting proof of continuity of $\log x$ using given prerequisites

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

I was given this question in my analysis class:

> Prove that $\log x$ is continuous using the definition $``$If $f(x) = e^x$, then $\log x = f^{-1}(x)."$ You are allowed to use analytic properties of $e^x$.

This is my proof:

---

We use the fact that $f(x)=e^x$ is continuous at all points. Then $f(a,b)$ must be connected in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence an interval. Clearly $f(a,b)$ cannot be singleton, since if $p <q$ where $p,q \in (a,b)$, then $f(p) < f(q)$ since $f$ is strictly increasing.

If possible, let $f(a,b)$ contain its supremum. Then there exists $p \in f(a,b)$ such that $f(p) = \sup  f(a,b)$. However, since $(a,b)$ is open, $B(p, \varepsilon) \subseteq (a,b) \Rightarrow p+\varepsilon \in (a,b) \Rightarrow f(p+\varepsilon) \in f(a,b)$. But $f(p+\varepsilon) > f(p)$, which contradicts the fact that $f(p)$ is the supremum.

Similarly, $f(a,b)$ does not contain its infimum and hence any boundary point and is thus an open interval. By extension we can say that the image of any open set under $f$ is open since an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals.

Thus, $f$ is an open map, which implies that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

So I find this proof a bit shaky, and am unsure of its validity. Is this proof correct? Is there a better way it could be written?

Comment: It looks fine to me. It also generalizes to any increasing continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.